# Why was the 'taint' tag deleted from this question?

Tags: discussion, tags, specific-question

The question in question: [Is it true that that "more taint-absorbing items = less protection against taint"?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/130290/is-it-true-that-that-more-taint-absorbing-items-less-protection-against-taint)

A moderate rep user created a tag that, as far as I can tell, accurately describes the content of their question.  A high rep user then deleted said tag.  This seems problematic to me, because it seems-- in the absence of any reason for or against said tags existence-- to contravene our typical folksonomic tagging practices.

Should said tag have been removed?  Would it be okay for me, disagreeing with said removal, to add it back?  Would that have been okay without a meta?

Comment: Revision history suggests the tag has been added and removed twice now. Let's not add it back yet since this constitutes an edit war. First we should discuss the removal here to see if there is a compelling reason to leave it removed.

Comment: This is definitely a situation for meta, edit wars are terrible and the tag has been added and removed twice already. Really, it probably should have gone to meta before it got added or removed the second time, unless there was discussion somewhere else (chat or comments that are now deleted).

Comment: I deleted this tag because it has no description and there were too few question with it (only two at the moment). I was thinking it was added by mistake.

Comment: @enkryptor Remember: Every tag starts with only a single question.

Comment: @WeckarE. why are you so sure? we can tag existing questions as well

Comment: @enkryptor and then still one will be the first.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

## Seems Legit to add it

Taint appears to be a mechanic that does have special properties. We've got other tags based on mechanics.

Don't see any issue why this shouldn't get it's own tag.

Comment: Absolutely this - it feels like someone assuming that the tag was too specific or wouldn't get enough use, neither of which I think applies here

Comment: @Wibbs and neither of which is sufficient reason to override another user's tag creation privilege without so much as a comment imho.